# Angular 7 + Routing + discrepancy

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular7

In my angular 7 code, i have following in the Routing Module:

```
{
    path: 'campaigns', component: PortalComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
        { path: '', component: CampaignListingComponent },
        { path: 'details/:id', component: CampaignDetailsComponent },
        { path: 'create', component: CreateCampaignComponent      }
    ]
}
```

In portalComponent, ngOnInit(), i have following:-

```
this.routerSubs = this.activatedRoute.params
.subscribe((params) => {
    console.log('router url=', this.router.url);
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.routingService.setbreadCrumbUrl(this.router.url);
    });
});

this.breadCrumbSubs = this.routingService.breadCrumbEmitter
.subscribe((breadcrumb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.breadcrumbEvent = breadcrumb;
        console.log('breadcrumb event=', this.breadcrumbEvent );
    });
});
```

When, `this.router.navigate(['/campaigns/create'])` gets called, i find that sometimes, `ngOnInit()` of portalComponent, does not get called, directly CreateCampaignComponent gets called. Why is this happening, as according to routing module, `PortalComponent` and then, `CreateCampaignComponent` should get called??

Comment: Do you have 2 router-outlets in your application? If you only have 1 only the child will render.

Comment: Can you tell what you mean by one or two? I also have this:    {
        path: 'search', component: PortalComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
            { path: '', component: SearchComponent },
            { path: 'edit/:id', component: SearchComponent },
        ]
    },

Comment: if you are already on the path and it calls the child routes it will only generate the ngOnInit of the parent route once.